# can you help me,how to insert a placeholder in settings.bundle?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have added  `settings.bundle` to my app,i'm displaying a textfield with title using `settings.bundle` in settings,but I need *insert/add a placeholder to textfield*, is it possible in `settings.bundle`,if yes,please help me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently settings.bundle does not allow you to add placeholder text for text field. The text field type displays a title (optional) and an editable text field. You can use this type for preferences that require the user to specify a custom string value.

There are some preference control types that are allowed.
Follow this: [LINK](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH6-SW5)

Comment: i understand that but i saw some sample code, that apps contains the placeholder in the settings.bundle how is that possible?